# Application launch from c command in window OS

Tags: c++, c, windows

I want to make an console application of c which can run other applications (exe files). Kindly guide me how can I make it possible so that from my c code i can run other executable files in window OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the `CreateProcess` Windows API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Could you kindly explain little bit more specific?

Comment: @Arman:  There are five pages of specifics in the linked MSDN documentation for `CreateProcess`.  It tells you which header to include (windows.h), which library to link (kernel32.lib, which should be linked by default), and what the function parameters are.  If you can tell me what, specifically, is unclear, perhaps I can explain.